# Google Domain forward POST request from "@" to "www"

Tags: redirect, heroku, subdomain, http-redirect, google-domain-api

**I want my Heroku web app on www.mydomain.com to receive POST requests sent to mydomain.com**

I created an app on Heroku, and intended on linking it to my root/bare domain (@) hosted by Google Domain. However, Heroku only provides CNAME, and Google Domain doesn't accept CNAME for root domain. I followed the workaround by linking my Heroku web app to www subdomain, and setting up a subdomain redirect from @ to www.

This works fine for the web app to show, but subdomain forward only forwards GET requests. My POST requests to root domain aren't forwarded to www (the app itself). I understand that http protocol only forwards GET via 301 redirect. Is there a workaround for this?